# Navigating through pages without refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have an admin panel created with bootstrap and integrated with Laravel and what I want to do is navigating through the tabs without refreshing the browser. How can I edit the code to achieve that?

The admin panel: https://www.bootstrapdash.com/product/star-admin-free/

Answer (score 0):

It's complex and you must to use a JavaScript framework like ReactJs or AngularJS to create SPA (single page application) application ... in react you can do this by "Route" component.

Comment: So it is impossible to use Bootstrap for this goal?

Comment: humm ... it is possible by Javascript and Bootstrap but it's very hard and complex.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can do that?

Comment: I hope this link helps you [https://www.sitepoint.com/single-page-app-without-framework]

Comment: bootstrap only helps you to create responsive web pages ... and has some tools for speed up developing web pages.

Comment: I have already build my project using that admin panel.. and now I know that is impossible to achieve this goal. Thanks for your time!

Comment: your welcome @Hakim2000 if my answer helps you to improve yourself ... you makes me happy by vote to my answer ... wish you all the best.